# Identify a re-integrated branch

Tags: svn, powershell, visualsvn-server

I am new to svn/subversion and am hoping someone can provide guidance. I am currently writing a PowerShell script which should ultimately provide some automation for daily 'catch-up' merges from trunk to multiple feature branches.

What I am trying to find out is if there is a way to identify branches that have been re-integrated with trunk so I can exclude them from any merge I automate.

I have searched any available documentation but not finding anything I can use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to read and parse the [`svn:mergeinfo`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.mergeinfo.html) properties on your branches.  Note that they are set only if a Subversion client of version ≥ 1.5 was used to perform a merge.

See also [this](https://www.open.collab.net/community/subversion/articles/merge-info.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I am already parsing some mergeinfo  properties as it is so I need to investigate further.